# Repopulate form data when validation fails in aspnet core Razor Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Thanks in advance for any help

I am working in aspnet core 2.1 razor pages. I need to repopulate form data when validation fails or ModelState is Invalid.
In MVC, we can use `return View(model)` but how to do that in aspnet core 2.1 razor page.

I tried `return Page()`, but that fires server side validation but does not repopulate data in form

Need Help...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Repopulation of the form values occurs automatically if you

1. Use the `[BindProperty]` attribute on the relevant PageModel properties,
2. Use the `asp-for` attribute in your [input tag helpers](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/input-tag-helper) to establish two-way binding in the UI (Razor content page)
3. Call `return Page()` in the event that `ModelState.IsValid == false`.

Here are the minimal steps required to demonstrate this:

A form:

```
<form method="post">
<input asp-for="FirstName"/><span asp-validation-for="FirstName"></span><br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And a PageModel:

```
public class FormValidationModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty, StringLength(5)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }
        return RedirectToPage("index");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike for Reply. Well i know this can work but what it does not work when you bind a property with dropdown(select). for example if i bind a dropdown and select its value to "ABC" on form and post back , and if model state fails, i can't rebind that select list and make ABC as selected value on form

Comment: Mike Brind, i sorted this our. Thanks for you help

Comment: How did you sort it?

Comment: @JacobAlley The select tag helper will automatically sort it for you if the property used to represent the selected value is made bindable by adding the `[BindProperty]` attribute to it.

Comment: @JacobAlley For the select list binding to work after validation fails, you also need to ensure the value of the select name attribute matches the name of the property to which you are binding. Ex: If you were binding to `Car.Color`, your select list would be `<select name="Car.Color"...>`.